# How to use two opencv versions in my solution c++

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I need to use both, OpenCV 2.2.0 and OpenCV 2.4.9 in the same Visual Studio 2010 solution. I can't use different solutions (a different solution for each OpenCV library version) because some projects in the solution (.sln file) use OpenCV 2.2.0 and others use OpenCV 2.4.9.

Is there an easy way to do that without raising any name conflicts between both versions of OpenCV?

This is my problem:
I have a.exe, b.lib and c.lib. And a.exe uses OpenCV 2.2.0 libs, b.lib and c.lib. But b.lib uses OpenCV 2.4.9 and c.lib. Finally c.lib uses OpenCV 2.2.0

I am not able to achieve that b.lib uses OpenCV 2.4.9 libs

Comment: afaik you can set individual libraries to the single projects of a solution, can't you?

Comment: in this case only one of them is a Win32 consol application, others are libraries

Comment: so you can link different openCV versions to different project libraries? What's the error when trying to link those project libraries to your win32 app?